# How do I model time-based events in haskell?

Tags: haskell, frp

I'm building a queue multiplexer in haskell, partly as a way to learn and partly as a replacement for some dodgy shell scripts.

What it does is periodically connect to each queue (we're using rabbitmq) in turn to measure the queue depth. If the main system is currently consuming from a queue and that queue has messages, we do nothing. If the connected queue is empty we switch to the queue with the most messages on it. If all queues are empty we do nothing.  So far so good.

I also need a time-based switch, such that if the main application has been connected to a queue for more than 1 hour and the queue is empty, then switch even if all other queues are empty.

I'm thinking that I want something that emits events periodically that will trigger the next cycle of behavior, something like 'check' events every minute and 'time-switch' events every hour.

Is there an idiomatic way to model time-based events in haskell?

Comment: Do you want to *model* the time events, or you want the time events?

Comment: Sounds like you might enjoy Erlang a bit more for this task....

Comment: [_Push-Pull FRP_](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/push-pull-frp.pdf) describes an efficient implementation of `Event` and `Behaviour` (as well as a formal semantics for each).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, this sounds like a job for `Control.Concurrent`. The parts you'd use would be `forkIO` to spawn one of haskell's lightweight threads to handle your timing loop, and a `Chan` to receive timing signals.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import Control.Monad (forever)

main = do
  -- channel to receive messages from the timing thread
  chan <- newChan :: IO (Chan String)

  -- spawn a new thread to send periodic signals
  forkIO $ forever $ do
    writeChan chan "hi!"
    threadDelay $ 1 * 1000 * 1000 -- delay in microseconds

  -- in the main thread, listen for messages from the chan.
  forever $ readChan chan >>= print
```

To expand on this, instead of writing `String`s to the `Chan` you could make an ADT for your events, something like:

```
data Event = CheckEvent | SwitchEvent deriving Show
```

And then have your listening thread do different things based on the event type.